# Android SurfaceView : cannot build when add callback

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview

I have implemented custom Android SurfaceView and meet error when I add callback for it.

Here is my code for class `SurfaceView`:

```
public class AndroidSurface extends SurfaceView {

    public SurfaceHolder holder;

    public AndroidSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                    int width, int height) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


        });
    }
}
```

When I add this view to `layout.xml`, for example :

```
<com.app.AndroidSurface
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rightBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" />
```

I will met error when show in `Graphical Layout` : failed to instantiate. (at Plugin : com.android.ide.eclipse.adt) and when run this project, I will have exception. When view in LogCat, I see that Java Null Point Exception.

The strange thing is : if I remove `holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {...` no error met.

This looks strange too me, please tell me how to fixed this.

@ Edited : and the problem because when I `getHolder`, it doesn't return `surface holder`, so holder is null, I don't know why.

Thanks :)

Comment: Post the logcat. Check if the holder is null.   Click on the line where you package name is shown in red. This will take to exactl stop.

Comment: You can also debug and set a breakpoint on the holder to see if it is null.

Comment: post getHolder() please.  It might not be working correctly.

Comment: @CodeDroid oh, yes, you right, `holder`is null, and I don't think this before. But, why it is null, please help me. Thanks :)

Comment: If you wrote it, you should know what is returning null or how its null.

Comment: Oh. I have a silly mistake, when I create this class, I have created a getter with this which name is : `getHolder`, that why my program went wrong !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your context and make sure you are doing things in the correct order with respect to your lifecycle. Check out this post [surfaceView.getHolder not returning SurfaceHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852740/surfaceview-getholder-not-returning-surfaceholder)